# MVC model design for entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to keep track of Employees in my database.

I have an entity class:

```
[Table(Name = "Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a page to add an employee to the database. So I created a ViewModel:

```
public class EmployeesAddViewModel
{
    public Employee employee { get; set; }        
}
```

I created the ViewModel like this because I plan on adding other things to the model later that aren't in the Employees table. I just wanted to start out with this to see if everything worked correctly.

And I have my page:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EmployeesAddViewModel>" ... %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Employees", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

But when I view my page, it doesn't show any form fields for my model, it doesn't show anything.

Do I need to have fields in my model for each entity field instead of just having the entire Employee class in my model? I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Employee)`

The default editor template doesn't consider complex type properties.